# Font loading OK in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox (all on Mac)

Tags: html, css

OK, I have reached the pulling my hair out stage.

I have created the below simple example. Basically Safari displays both fonts correctly, yet both Chrome and Firefox will not display the Helvetica font. Both fonts reside in the same folder, along with this test HTML. Anyone any ideas? - I have tried Helvetica Heavy Condensed from two sources, both same effect. See images.

```
<head>
<style>
@font-face 
{
    font-family: "HelvHvCn";
    src: url('HelvHvCn.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face 
{
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
h1
{
    font-family: HelvHvCn;
}
h2
{
    font-family: BebasNeue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This font only works in Safari</h1>
<h2>This font works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, not allowed to upload images yet. Basically <h2> font is fine, but <h1> font is displayed OK in Safari but reverts to Times New Roman in Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Webfont implementations are a bit screwy, so you need to use a carefully phrased @font-face declaration to get it rendering reliably xbrowser.

Providing you have the license to use it as a webfont, run the TTF through a service like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to generate the eot, woff and svg webfonts, then try this syntax in your CSS...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your-custom-font';
    src: url('your-custom-font.eot');
    src: url('your-custom-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('your-custom-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('your-custom-font.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('your-custom-font.svg#your-custom-font') format('svg');
    }

body {
       font-family: 'your-custom-font', sans-serif;
}
```

Its probably also worth noting that woff files occasionally look fine on Mac Chrome, and pretty gash on Win Chrome. You may want to mess about with *-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;* and in some edgecases tweak the font order, or even ditch the woff altogether.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I am using a licence free Helvetica, but as a quick check I just used my Mac-installed Helevetica Heavy Condensed TTF and it works fine. So there is an issue with the font I am using not being liked by Chrome or Firefox, weird that Safari is OK with it though.

Comment: No worries, hope you get it sorted :)

I'd still be inclined to generate the alternate file versions - I'd assume system fonts would probably render fine even if the @font-face wasn't working?

Comment: Yes, it drops back to Arial if I specify it. But its the Condensed bit thats important as all the article titles drop onto 2 lines which messes up formatting.